# R plumber APIs: How do I specify input types?

Tags: r, api, plumber

I have a plumber API.

```
#* API title
#* @param param1
#*
#* @post /method_name
function(x) x
```

The default behaviour is to convert `param1` to a string, then I would need to use `as.numeric(x)` in the function body. Is there a way to specify the input type of each parameter? And if I have 40 parameters, all of which are numeric, is there a way to specify every parameter as numeric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the type for a specific parameter using `param:type`. Let's say you want `param1` to be an integer, then we can do:

```r
#* API title
#* @param param1:int
#*
#* @post /method_name
function(x) x
```

I'm unaware of how to specify 40 parameters in an automated way that isn't just `#* @param paramx:int` repeated for x from 1 to 40. You can see the details on type in the [annotations documentation](https://www.rplumber.io/articles/annotations.html) for `plumber`.

Comment: I was hoping their would be a solution like this but couldn't find it anywhere! This is perfect thanks, no need to automate for more parameters as this is succinct and easy.